# NHIbernate: Get children object filtered by parent object's property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, criteria, queryover

I use Fluent NHibernate to map my entities.

My classes:

```
public class Email
{
    public virtual int Id           { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Status    { get; set; }
    public virtual string Login     { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password  { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile  { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public virtual int Id             { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string ProfilePath { get; set; }
    public virtual Proxy Proxy        { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created   { get; set; }
}

public class Proxy
{
    public virtual int Id           { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Status    { get; set; }
    public virtual string Ip        { get; set; }
    public virtual string Port      { get; set; }
    public virtual string Type      { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

EntityMaps:

```
public class EmailMap : ClassMap<Email>
{
    public EmailMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id);
        Map(c => c.Status).Not.Nullable();
        Map(c => c.Login).Not.Nullable();
        Map(c => c.Password).Not.Nullable();
        Map(c => c.Created).Not.Nullable();
        References(c => c.Profile).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class ProfileMap : ClassMap<Profile>
{
    public ProfileMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id);
        Map(c => c.ProfilePath).Not.Nullable();
        Map(c => c.Created).Not.Nullable();
        References(c => c.Proxy).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class ProxyMap : ClassMap<Proxy>
{
    public ProxyMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id);
        Map(c => c.Status).Not.Nullable();
        Map(c => c.Ip).Not.Nullable();
        Map(c => c.Port).Not.Nullable();
        Map(c => c.Type).Not.Nullable();
        Map(c => c.Created).Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Each Email has only one Profile. Each Profile has only one Proxy.
I want to keep Proxy class independent (I mean that I don't want to modify it or adapt for other project) and so I don't want to map to parent objects like Profile, Email. Because those collection of parent object may be not useful in other project. That's why I made "one way" relation (please correct me if I am wrong or missunderstanding). So I can't get Email from child Profile (the same with Profile and Proxy).

Now I am trying to write the method using QueryOver which returns Proxies which have not been used since "custom interval" (input). So in case of Email, I have to get all Emails which are created since "input", get their Profile, get their Proxy. And at last step inverse selection. So I get proxies which have not been used in email project for custom interval. 
I realized it using ISQLQuery:

```
SELECT *
FROM proxy
WHERE proxy.Id
NOT IN
(
    SELECT profile.Proxy_id
    JOIN profile ON email.Profile_id = profile.id
    WHERE email.Created > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
);
```

I am not sure about "one way" relation.

I think it makes entity universal. I mean it may be useful for many other projects. I don't want to add any parent collection (Profile) for child (Proxy) each time I create a new project. For example I need to get proxy for other classes (not Email). And I use the same method from my ProxyRepository.

Ofcourse input parameters will contain data about parent entity (beacuse parent entity contains property).

Sorry, for my english.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
var proxies = session.QueryOver<Email>.Where(email => email.Created < DateTime.Now() - TimeSpan.FromDays(1)).Select(email => email.Profile.Proxy);
```